# How to buy Czech vignette by credit/debit card?

Tags: driving, czech-republic, vignettes

Is it possible to buy Czech vignette sticker at gas stations and pay by card?

I noticed that sellers at some kiosks at rest stations near the border (eg. near Austrian or Slovakian border) only accept cash and exploit that by applying high "spread" when exchanging Euro or other currencies to CZK (Czech Krona).

Some gas station where I asked did not offer the stickers. How can I find out where the stickers are available?

Comment: Did you actually find a gas station in the Czech Republic *not* selling vignettes, or was that abroad?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The official motorway website for Czech Republic offer some details on what parts of the motorway are charged and which are not. Most petrol stations sell them and you can ensure you go past one by using one of the following:

> When entering the Czech Republic on motorways D1 (from Poland near
>   Bohumín), D2 (from Slovakia near Břeclav), D5 (from Germany near
>   Rozvadov) and D8 (from Germany near Petrovice), the sticker can be
>   bought on the first rest area after the border. ([source](http://www.motorway.cz/stickers#where-to-buy-a-sticker))

If you enter the Czech Republic by one of the free motorway areas, or a non motorway road, you can also buy them at most post offices, but unless it is in a city or large town they might not take card at all, or unless you spend over a specified amount.

Note that Road and Motorway Directorate (ŘSD) does not have its own selling points.

Comment: I'd just like to add for future reference that unless you're in a small city or a really small shop it's 99% possible to pay using a card (VISA/MASTERCARD are univesally accepted). It's made possible because anyone selling anything commercially (with a few exceptions) has to use electronic evidence system that sends the transaction data to the government for tax evidence. Since everybody had to buy computerized cash registers, they mostly contain the option to pay using a card with little added charge to the price of the register.